# Obvious MySQL error?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error and no matter how I gazillion-check it, even with others, I can't find the mistake:

Query:

```
INSERT INTO keymaps ( CharacterID, Key, Type, Action ) VALUES ( '100002', '18', '4', '0' )
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key, Type, Action ) VALUES ( '100002', '18', '4', '0' )' at line 1
```

The table is called `keymaps`, and it contains:

- `int(11) ID`  (auto increment)
- `int(11) CharacterID`
- `int(11) Key`
- `smallint(6) Type`
- `smallint(6) Action`

None of the fields allow null.

What's the matter?

*Note*: I didn't know whether to post this on SF or SO, but I thought it would be more appropriate on SO as it is language syntax. Feel free to move it.

Comment: key is reserved word so quote it or better still rename the field, also, remove quotes from numeric values - they arent strings !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Key` is a reserved word. You need to wrap it in backticks.

```
INSERT INTO keymaps ( `CharacterID`, `Key`, `Type`, `Action` )
```

[mySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something that obvious.

Comment: @El Yobo: SO requires me to wait at least 15 minutes.