# Insert md5 hash into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm trying to insert a md5 hash into a mysql database table with php.

```
        $key = $email . date('mY');
        $key = md5($key);

        $query = "INSERT INTO confirm (key, angemeldet_von, geschlecht, geburtstag)
            VALUES('$key', '$angemeldet_von', '$geschlecht', '$geburtstag')";
        $confirm = mysql_query($query, $connectionID)
          or die('failed connecting: ' . mysql_error());
```

This query returns the error:

```
failed connecting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, angemeldet_von, geschlecht, geburtstag) VALUES('8fe3ec75be1a43b49eacd3' at line 1
```

But the same query works well when I leave out the key column and its value.
So what is the problem here?
Mysql:

```
key varchar(128)    utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obvious MySQL error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393190/obvious-mysql-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` is a [`reserved word`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Enclose it in backticks !

Like this..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO confirm (`key`, angemelde
                               ^   ^ ------ Like that
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !
                                   ^   ^